# how to trigger a css animation on scroll in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a  website where I want to enable an element to fade in when i scroll down to a certain point. I've tried implementing this using vanilla HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, but the element is not triggering the animation on scroll as expected. I've followed various tutorials and suggestions, but I'm still facing difficulties. Could you please help me troubleshoot and provide guidance on how to make a fade-in animation trigger on scroll?

Used code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="anim">hi</h1>
</body>
<script>
    const obj = document.getElementById("anim")
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    
        if(height  > 100) {
            $(obj).addClass("fade");
    
        }else{
            $(obj).addClass("fade");
        }
    });

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want our help with troubleshooting, then you need present a proper [mre] of the issue first of all.

Comment: If you're looking at a vanilla JS solution there is the new [Intersection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code :

1. You are targeting the element by ID but you have provided class = "anim" in your html code. Give id = "anim" to the h1 element.
2. Include necessary libraries cdn in your code i.e. jquery,vanilla,etc.

I thinks with these changes your code will work fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).